# How can I fix TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' on travis cause the test run fine on my local machine

Tags: django, python-3.x, travis-ci

Am setting up Travis for a Django project and I want to be able to get test coverage but am getting some error and Here's a link to my [Travis build](https://travis-ci.org/j0flintking02/Esacco)

Comment: Don't use dj_database_url, it's not been updated for over a year...

Comment: what would you suggest I use instead

Comment: Just use basic Django settings to define your databases

Comment: ok let me try that